# How to convert GDI+ Status to string?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+

Actually, the subject. I haven't found any standard way to convert GDI+ `Status` (error status returned by GDI+ methods) to string, something like `FormatMessage()`

Comment: [GDI+ Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534175(v=vs.85).aspx) is enum which in turn is integral values. So you're basically asking converting integers into string or converting the *labels* in the enum into string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert *labels* in [GDI+ Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) into string, then the simplest thing you can do is this:

```
const char* StatusMsgMap[] = 
{
    "Ok",               //StatusMsgMap[Ok] = "Ok";
    "GenericError",     //StatusMsgMap[GenericError] = "GenericError";
    "InvalidParameter", //StatusMsgMap[InvalidParameter] = "InvalidParameter";
    "OutOfMemory",      //StatusMsgMap[OutOfMemory] = "OutOfMemory";
    //so on
};

//Usage:
 std::string error = StatusMsgMap[status]; // where status is Status type!
```

Or if you want more descriptive message, then this:

```
const char* StatusMsgMap[] =
{
    "the method call was successful",
    "there was an error on the method call, which is identified as something other than those defined by the other elements of this enumeration",
    "one of the arguments passed to the method was not valid",
    //so on
};
```

Since there are only 22 labels in the [Status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enum, creating a `StatusMsgMap` in the above way would not be much task, in my opinion. 5 minute is more than enough!

Comment: I guess that should be a compile-time static constant array and not an STL map. The Status values start at 0.

Comment: @Sebastian: Oops... I just made that. :-)

Comment: 5 mins? :) these constants aren't too self-descriptive, so I have to guess their good description. as I understood, there's no standard way to receive these descriptions, right?

Comment: @Andy: The description is from MSDN itself. You don't have to "guess" anything. Each enum value has specific meaning and message; see this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534175(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here's something I wrote that uses hardcoded values.

```cpp
std::string statusString(const Gdiplus::Status status) {
    switch (status) {
        case Gdiplus::Ok: return "Ok";
        case Gdiplus::GenericError: return "GenericError";
        case Gdiplus::InvalidParameter: return "InvalidParameter";
        case Gdiplus::OutOfMemory: return "OutOfMemory";
        case Gdiplus::ObjectBusy: return "ObjectBusy";
        case Gdiplus::InsufficientBuffer: return "InsufficientBuffer";
        case Gdiplus::NotImplemented: return "NotImplemented";
        case Gdiplus::Win32Error: return "Win32Error";
        case Gdiplus::Aborted: return "Aborted";
        case Gdiplus::FileNotFound: return "FileNotFound";
        case Gdiplus::ValueOverflow: return "ValueOverflow";
        case Gdiplus::AccessDenied: return "AccessDenied";
        case Gdiplus::UnknownImageFormat: return "UnknownImageFormat";
        case Gdiplus::FontFamilyNotFound: return "FontFamilyNotFound";
        case Gdiplus::FontStyleNotFound: return "FontStyleNotFound";
        case Gdiplus::NotTrueTypeFont: return "NotTrueTypeFont";
        case Gdiplus::UnsupportedGdiplusVersion: return "UnsupportedGdiplusVersion";
        case Gdiplus::GdiplusNotInitialized: return "GdiplusNotInitialized";
        case Gdiplus::PropertyNotFound: return "PropertyNotFound";
        case Gdiplus::PropertyNotSupported: return "PropertyNotSupported";
        default: return "Status Type Not Found.";
    }
}
```

Use as follows:

```cpp
const std::string statusMsg = statusString(theStatus);
//And then just output it.
std::cout << "Operation returned message: " << statusMsg << '\n';
```